# c# - Как сохранять фильтр при пагинации? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, mvc, фильтрация, пагинация

Необходимо при переходе на другую страницу, запомнить то, что произошло на первой. То есть фильтрацию таблицы. И соответственно будет уменьшение количества страниц. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Класс для фильтрации и пагинации:

```
public class HomeRepairListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<HomeRepair> HomeRepairs { get; set; }
    public SelectList Status { get; set; }
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Код контроллера:

```
public ActionResult Index(string status, int page = 1)
    {
        var owners = db.Owners;
        ViewBag.Owners = owners;

        IQueryable<HomeRepair> homeRepairs = db.HomeRepairs;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status) && !status.Equals("Все"))
        {
            homeRepairs = homeRepairs.Where(p => p.RepairStatus == status);
        }

        int pageSize = 2;
        homeRepairs = homeRepairs.OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);

        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo { PageNumber = page, PageSize = pageSize, TotalItems = db.HomeRepairs.Count() };

        HomeRepairListViewModel hrlv = new HomeRepairListViewModel
        {
            HomeRepairs = homeRepairs.ToList(),
            Status = new SelectList(new List<string>()
            {
                "Все",
                "Ремонт запланирован",
                "Начат",
                "Окончен"
            }),
            PageInfo = pageInfo
        };

        return View(hrlv);
    }
```

Хелпер для пагинации:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PageInfo pageInfo,  Func<int,string> pageUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();

            if (i == pageInfo.PageNumber)
            {
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
            }
            tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
            result.Append(tag.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
```

Фрагменты кода Index.cshtml :
Вызов хелпера

```
<div class="btn-group">
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PageInfo,  x => Url.Action("Index",  new { page = x }))</div>
```

Форма для фильтрации

```html
<h1>Список домов</h1>
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label class="control-label">Статус ремонта</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("status", Model.HomeRepairs as SelectList,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        <input type="submit" value="Фильтр" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Сохраняйте и передавайте в запросе фильтр, сортировку и пейджинг и не будет подобных проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу такое решение:

1. Возвращаешь вьюху
2. Пользователь делает всю необходимую фильтрацию
3. Далее `AJAX` запросами при переходе со страницы на страницу пересылаешь фильтр в контроллер и возвращаешь частичное представление

Еще одним решением будет-это сохранять фильтр в Сессии

Answer (score 0):

Я воспользовался Session, спасибо, iluxa1810.
Добавил в методе контроллера `Session["status"] = status;`
Поменял местами 
`PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo { PageNumber = page, PageSize = pageSize, TotalItems = homeRepairs.Count() };` и

```
        homeRepairs = homeRepairs.OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);`
```

чтобы правильно считало количество страниц и изменил передачу параметров

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PageInfo,  (x) => Url.Action("Index", "Home",  new { page = x, status = Session["status"] }))
```